# Disable selection of a single UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How do you disable selecting only a single cell in a UITableView?  I have several, and I only want the last to be disabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableview: How to Disable Selection for Some Rows but Not Others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267993/uitableview-how-to-disable-selection-for-some-rows-but-not-others)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = ...

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}
```

Comment: This will prevent the cell from appearing to be selected, but `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will still be called.

Comment: Using both `cell.selectionStyle = .None` and `cell.userInteractionEnabled = false` combined will cover most scenarios.

Answer (score 53):

To stop just some cells being selected use:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

As well as preventing selection, this also stops tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: being called for the cells that have it set. It will also make voiceover treat it the same as a dimmed button (which may or may not be what you want).

Note that if you have interactive elements in the cell (ie. switches/buttons), you'll need to use `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` instead and then make sure to ignore taps on the cell in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Try doing this on the view that receives the highlight. Otherwise, it is the same as disabling the cell.

Comment: I can't use this because it also disables `cell.accessoryView`, which I've set to a `UIButton` that I want to be tappable.

Comment: Additionally, this will cause Voice Over to incorrectly treat the cell as a dimmed button instead of static text (with an optional accessory).

Comment: @Endersstocker Thanks, that's useful extra info - I've mentioned that in my answer so it's more prominent. (I guess in some situations that may be want people want, depending why they're disabling the cell?)

Answer (score 19):

Throw this in your custom Table VC:

```
// cells lacking UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator will not be selectable
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType != UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator) {
        return nil;
    }
    return indexPath;
}

// disabled cells will still have userinteraction enabled for their subviews
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled forTableViewCell:(UITableViewCell *)tableViewCell
{
    tableViewCell.accessoryType = (enabled) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    // if you dont want the blue selection on tap, comment out the following line
    tableViewCell.selectionStyle = (enabled) ? UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue : UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```

Then to enable/disable selection for someTableViewCell, do this:

```
[self setEnabled:state forTableViewCell:someTableViewCell];
```

You're done and can ship.

Answer (score 11):

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self numberOfRowsInSection] == [indexPath row]) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return indexPath;
    }
}
```

the last row of the table will not be selected

Comment: This will prevent the cell from actually being selected, but it will still be highlighted when the user touches it

Comment: Sorry, need to add UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone style to the cell

Comment: I might add that setting the tableview selection style should be done in cellForRowAtIndexPath: to avoid lag when loading the TableView (the table view takes a good 1-2 to disable selection for the cell).

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned [in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11165274/1355058) all the above methods are not solving the problem precisely. The correct way of disabling a cell is through the method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and in that method one has to use

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

which disables cell selection but *still* allows the user to interact with subviews of the cell such as a UISwitch.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution that I have found to this only makes use of the delegate method willDisplayCell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([indexPath row] == 0) //<-----ignores touches on first cell in the UITableView
    {                        //simply change this around to suit your needs
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.textLabel.enabled = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

You don't have to take any further action in the delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath to ensure that the selection of this cell is ignored.  All touches on this cell will be ignored and the text in the cell will be grayed out as well.

Answer (score 0):

with iOS 6.

You can use the following delegate method and return `NO` in case you don't it to be selected and `YES` in case you want it to be selected.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return indexPath.section == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in swift:

```
self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wondering how to achieve this in swift then here is my code. I am using Xcode 7 and tested using iPad Retina(iOS 9).

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle .None
cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Try to place this two line code whether you want. In my case I have used this in this method for displaying cells.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Remember this two line code will block any kind of selection or interaction to your cells but you can only use the first line individually if you want. That is...

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle .None
```

Only this line will block the selection to your cells.

However the second line will make the cell "Read-Only". That is..

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Thanks

Hope this helped.