# iOS: clicking on a view inside a TableCellView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I placed a small `UIView` inside a `UITableViewCell`.

- In case of a tapping **on** such `UIView`, I would like to open a popup.
- In case of a tapping **outside** such `UIView`, I would like to perform what it's defined in the `UITableView` "*didSelectRowAtIndexPath*" function.

What it's happening at the moment is that when I click **on** the view both things happen: the popup is opened and the "*didSelectRowAtIndexPath*" function is trigged.

How can I make sure that when I click on that `UIView` the "*didSelectRowAtIndexPath*" function is not triggered?

**current implementation:**

I defined a `UITapGestureRecognizer` for the `UIView` inside my custom `UITableViewCell` class.

`let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyCustomTableViewCell.clickOnHelp(_:)))
myClickAreaUIView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)`

Comment: may I suggest to change the UIView to a UIButton and handle the touch with a touchUpInside on the button?

Comment: Where and how do you handle uitapgesture on the view?

Comment: I think there's a way to set up views to not forward their touch events.  I think buttons do that by default, but things like views do not.

Comment: yes, I am actually currently using a `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: You can take button in view. and manage it's click event.

Comment: add your code that how you adding tapgesture and managing your cell, because default behavior will not result as mentioned by you in question. I mean, for example you have cell and you put uiview in it and add gesture recognizer on it, and then click to that view, it will not called `didselectrowatindexpath`. This is the default behavior.

Comment: Hi Ketan, I added my current implementation code.

Comment: By any chance are you drawing a custom shape in that UIView?

Comment: @Dravidian no, It's just an empty UIView, constrained by the position and width of some other views

Comment: @ddb do you have any idea if a plain `UIView` can achieve the same of a `UIButton` by changing some properties?

Comment: I wrote an answer, please try it, @DanieleB

Comment: Have you checked this, @Daniele B? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429652/detecting-uibutton-pressed-in-tableview-swift-best-practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I suggest is to change the `UIView` to a `UIButton` and handle the touch with a `touchUpInside` on the button.

This way you will reach your objective, as `UIButton` automatically prevents touch event forwarding to superview

Comment: This answer suggests that one change their current implementation. Some designs may not work with UIButtons instead of UIViews..

Comment: @programmingandroid you may be right, but it's quite uncommon someone tries to make an UIView behave as an UIButton without using an UIButton :))) also I have to say that an UIButton is an UIView

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the inner view's [exclusiveTouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/exclusiveTouch) property to `true`.

```
cell.tapView.exclusiveTouch = true
```

Comment: I just tried that, the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` still gets triggered

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to implement the following method of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` like below

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    print("in shouldReceiveTouch")
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    if ([...]){ // touch location is in the UIView
        print("touching UIView")
        return false // prevent from forwarding touch to superview
    } else {
        println("touching elsewhere")
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ddb! I solved the problem by changing the UIView to a UIButton and handling the touch with a touchUpInside on the button. If you are going to write an answer about that, I am going to accept it as the proper answer to this issue. Many Thanks!

Comment: could you write another answer, where you specify that solution alone? By accepting this answer, I would also accept the first part, which I haven't verified.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this method from `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
   return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a customClass for your `UIView` lets say `CustomView` of type `UIView`

Connect your `UIView`'s `@IBOutlet` conforming to *tableViewCell* of type **CustomView**

In **CustomView** class call this function

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    super.pointInside(point, withEvent: event)

    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, point)
}
```

This will tell you whether or not the location at which user tapped was contained inside that `UIView` bounds or not, if it returns *true* do pop up in your `UIGestureRecognizer` functions and follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/18606840/6297658 , if *false* do the opposite

Comment: i am looking forward to a solution to your prob, I could'nt check it , that would mean writing a whole new app, but did this work?

Answer (score -1):

just write this code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath() for did select prevent::

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath must work also, if user tap outside the subview, are you sure it will continue working?