# How to enable UITableView when there is text in a textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, text, uitextfield

I have two `textFields` and a `TableView`. The `Tableview` should initially be disabled (meaning the `labels` greyed out and the `cells` are not clickable). When both `textFields` have values, I want the `TableView` and the `tableViewCells` to be clickable and not greyed out. 
So far, I've added targets to both of the `textfields` to track when the user is editing:

```
var isUserEditing: Bool = false

func setup() {
        mealItemTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(userIsEditing), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
        priceTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(userIsEditing), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    }

@objc func userIsEditing(sender: UITextField) {
        sender.text = sender.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
        guard
            let mealtext = mealItemTextField.text, !mealtext.isEmpty,
            let pricetext = priceTextField.text, !pricetext.isEmpty
        else
        {
            isUserEditing = false
            return
        }
        isUserEditing = true
    }
```

Then I created an extension for `UITableViewCell` that basically "enables" and "disables" the `tableView` (retrieved from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905608/how-do-i-make-a-uitableviewcell-appear-disabled) thread):

```
  extension UITableViewCell {
    func enable(on: Bool) {
        for view in contentView.subviews {
            view.isUserInteractionEnabled = on
            view.alpha = on ? 1 : 0.5
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I implemented this method as well as the variable `isUserEditing` in my `viewForHeaderInSection`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let userModel = Data.userModels[section]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nameCell") as! NameHeaderTableViewCell
    cell.setup(model: userModel)
    cell.enable(on: false)
    if isUserEditing == true {
        cell.enable(on: true)
    }
    return cell.contentView
}
```

The `tableView` appears "disabled" when the view loads, however when I start typing in one or both of the `textFields`, it remains disabled. So obviously the `viewForHeaderInSection` isn't reloading, or being executed again.

Is there any way to achieve this? Can I run the `viewForHeaderInSection` in realtime and update automatically? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

[This should be the initial view when there is no text in the textField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkmRP.png)

[This should be the view after there is some text in both textFields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JssQ.png)

Comment: Could you please share demo app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tableView.reloadData() is missing due to which table view is not getting reloaded.

```
@objc func userIsEditing(sender: UITextField) {
       sender.text = sender.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
       guard
           let mealtext = mealItemTextField.text, !mealtext.isEmpty,
           let pricetext = priceTextField.text, !pricetext.isEmpty
       else
       {
           isUserEditing = false
       tableView.reloadData() // reload table view here
           return
       }
       isUserEditing = true
    tableView.reloadData() // reload table view here
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable your tableView as keyboard appeared  and textfields are empty or not you can check this by notifications;

in your ViewController class:

```
        override func viewDidLoad() {
             super.viewDidLoad()
             yourTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

         // check notifications if keyboard shown or not
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)     
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(hideKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

         // if your textFields out of your tableview
              yourTextField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
                yourTextField2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)

                }


 @objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){

     self.yourTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     print("Text changed")

  }

  // show keyboard function
  @objc func showKeyboard(notification: NSNotification){

  // You can disable your tableview or your cells in this case i just disable tableview.

     yourTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     print("keyboard appeared")
   }

   // this part is up to how you want to implement. If you want to keep tableview active after textField edited don't use this method

  @objc func hideKeyboard(notification: NSNotification){

   // You can disable your tableview or your cells
      yourTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
      print("keyboard disappeared")
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
   let userModel = Data.userModels[section]
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nameCell") as! NameHeaderTableViewCell

        // if your text Fields inside tableView tracking you textfield changes (in this case you couldn't disable tableView initially) 

   cell.yourTextField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
   cell.yourTextField2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
                return cell.contentView
   }
```

I hope this will solve your problem good luck.