# Can I disable the UITableView selection of the individual cell?

Tags: ios

When ever you tap on a row in a `UITableView`, the row is highlighted and selected. Is it possible to disable this so tapping a row does nothing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableview: How to Disable Selection for Some Rows but Not Others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267993/uitableview-how-to-disable-selection-for-some-rows-but-not-others)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

or `[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];`

Further, make sure you either don't implement `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in your `table view delegate` or explicitly exclude the cells you want to have no action if you do implement it.

Answer (score 4):

Implement `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method of `UITableView` and return `nil`.Returning nil from this method tells the table view to not select the row consequently `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method will not get called.But doing this does not prevent highlighting the row.To disable highlighting effect on row set cell selection style to`UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` as explained in the above answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just set :

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want stop highlighting use the code say: your desired value to be 19

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{
if(indexpath.row == '19')
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
else
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

}
```

But, if you want to control the selection of cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if(indexpath.row == '19')
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

for Swift 3 :

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was not working for me. This problem driving me crazy for awhile because it would look like a "glitch" on any selection when the next view loaded..

My SOLUTION: I had to go to the .xib file of the actual TableViewCell (my custom cell that I built) select the cell and select the CellView. (Make sure you select the Cell, and NOT a subview within it. It will turn Blue like the picture shows). On the left side click "Selection" -> "None". This SHOULD be the exact same as doing it with code, but for some reason it just wasn't working...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is for the case in which you have a **custom cell**, but I found this question when I was looking for the answer, so I thought I'd leave this here in case this helps others.

---

Go to your custom cell, and set `selectionStyle` to `.none` in the `awakeFromNib` method:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // disable selection
    selectionStyle = .none;
}
```

If you use this custom cell in multiple `UITableView`s, you only have to set it once in the custom cell instead of on every `UITableView` you use :)

Answer (score 0):

for Swift 4

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply do this for **OBJ C**:

```
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```