# IOS Disable UItableview Selection on All Cells but one Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

How can one disable selection on all `UITableviewCell`'s except for one in a `UITableview`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Deselect row
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    // NSLog(@"Row Selected = %li",(long)indexPath.row);

    self.selectedInvitedUserId = [[self.viewOrderUserArray valueForKey:@"InvitedUserId"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"Row selectedInvitedUserId = %@",self.selectedInvitedUserId);

    if( self.selectedInvitedUserId && [indexPath row] != 0 )
        {
            if ([[self.viewSelectedItemsArray lastObject] count] == 0)
            {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"delimenuFromViewOrderList" sender:self];
            }
            else
            {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewOrderSummaryFromOrderDetails" sender:self];
            }
        } 
}
```

I know of this to disable all cells.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: Are you using a custom cell ? @CapeFurSeal

Comment: Do you want to disable all cells except one Right ?

Comment: no just a normal tableview...

Comment: @Haroon  > Yes you are 100% correct

Comment: @CapeFurSeal if you downvoted my answer please explain why rather than just marking it as incorrect. I can't solve your issue if I don't know the problem

Comment: never down voted anyone;s answer although your answer does not help me as I want to enable only one cell in the uitableview to be selectable..

Comment: @CapeFurSeal ok fair enough. But that is exactly what my code shows. I've used this many times to make my cells not selectable

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the note under my code mentioning that there is 2 steps to this, 1. make sure the rows don't highlight. 2. check which row has been tapped. This will make which ever one you like selectable and the others not selectable

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableview: How to Disable Selection for Some Rows but Not Others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267993/uitableview-how-to-disable-selection-for-some-rows-but-not-others)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267993/uitableview-how-to-disable-selection-for-some-rows-but-not-others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this in the

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

callback. This is a setting on a cell that will be executed when it is tapped. It is not something you should try to manually manage

like so:

```
// Where indexPath != 0 points to the row you want to enable
if( self.selectedInvitedUserId && indexPath != 0 )
{
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}
else
{
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
}
```

**Note**

This will only stop it being highlighted. You will need to check inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` callback if its the correct row.

Comment: @FahimParkar I think you've misunderstood my code. I wasn't suggesting that it was for one user. The OP asked a question and gave sample code using `selectedInvitedUserId` in an if statement to make a decision. I simply copied something similar in my answer to him. I will however change it to exactly what the OP had, with a tweak for my code

Comment: yes, my mistake... I got... that's why removed the downvote and upvoted... but I would say not to use UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue and handle click action in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @FahimParkar ah ok, no problem, thanks for removing it. If you set all the cells to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` the user won't receive any indication that the cell was tapped. The OP may not want blue but thats up to him to decide or maybe ask himself. What my code has done is, it will only highlight in blue the row the OP wishes to be clickable and not the rest. The OP has largely already figure out what you have posted but has asked how to display only one, implying he is fine with how its running (defaulted to blue), but simply wants to prevent it happening on all cells

Comment: **NO**, with `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` just selection is disabled.. you can tap on cell and didSelectRowAtIndexPath is invoked too...

Comment: @FahimParkar yes, I have a note in my answer to that fact also

Comment: has someone else downvoted my answer, again without any indication as to why? if you feel something is incorrect feel free to downvote but also leave a comment. Clearly You think I have done something incorrect, if I have I would also like to know what this is

Comment: for me its not wrong, just I would say not to use `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` bcz that will make cell background as blue when clicked... that it...

Comment: @downvoter the OP has marked this as the top answer meaning it solved their issue. If you feel there is an issue with this answer please explain it so I can fix it. If not please remove it as several people including the OP disagree. Thank you

Comment: don't get panic with downvoters. Its their duty... :D

Comment: @FahimParkar just bugs me is all, I no it doesn't actually mean anything in the long run. Just annoy's me when I get an anonymous downvoter and have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I would suggest.

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` keep `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` alive for all cell.

Now you must be making action on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. There do like below.

```
if( userId == your_ignore_userid )
{
    // don't do anything
}
else
{
    // do action - like go to another view controller
}
```

Reason why not to use `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is because if user click on that cell (which you don't want to allow), background of that cell will become blue which will go against your app design and it will look ugly.

Hence I would suggest you to handle action in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Let me know if you have further questions.

### Note:

With `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` just cell selection is disabled.. You can tap on cell and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` gets invoked too...