# How do I hide the multi-select edit gui for certain cells in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, interface-builder, selection

I am using UITableView, setting editing true, and using these options in interface builder:

[image]

This shows a nice selection UI whose style I can modify and events I can react to:

[image]

I want to turn this off, but only for certain cells. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267993/uitableview-how-to-disable-selection-for-some-rows-but-not-others) and many similar questions, but they refer to a different type of selection in UITableView. `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None` and `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` do not allow me to block this type of selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to implement

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
  canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool

in your delegate ?

I believe it will allow you to obtain the results you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah man! High five! Need to implement `UITableViewDataSource`, and this works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(indexPath.row == index of cell you don't want the selection for)
{
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

cell.textLabel.text = [a objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

For example:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSArray *a = @[@"md",@"dh",@"kkd",@"dkkls"];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(indexPath.row == 2)
{
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

cell.textLabel.text = [a objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

it won't show selection for "kkd" in your tableview

Comment: As stated, `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None` does not block this type of selection, the kind caused by having an editable uiTableView

Comment: Can you share your code? I have tried above code on editable uiTableView and it is working