# UITableViewCell getting highlighted when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView inside my VC, and basically what I want is the first section of it be non-tappable. But I cannot use `isUserInteractionEnabled`
because I have UISwitch inside of each row of this section. Setting `selectionStyle` to `.none` changes nothing. I can only pick `No Selection` in the interface inspector to disable those rows, but it disables the entire table. What should I do?

**EDIT**

Here's my custom cell class

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {

        if highlighted {
            self.backgroundColor = ColorConstants.onTapColor
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if selected {
            self.backgroundColor = ColorConstants.onTapColor
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267993/uitableview-how-to-disable-selection-for-some-rows-but-not-others

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `selectionStyle` of all `UITableViewCells` in the first section to `.none` as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YOURIDENTIFIER")

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
    } else {
        cell.selectionStyle = .default
    }

    return cell
}
```

Then in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()`method you can check `if (indexPath.section != YOURSECTION)`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        // DO NITHING
    } else {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO WITH THE CELLS IN YOUR OTHER SECTIONS
    }
}
```

Comment: It still gets highlighted on tap, as I said. Mb the reason for that is that setting selectionStyle to none avoids executing didSelectRowAt, but it still calls willSelectRowAt

Comment: I found the reason and it was pretty silly of my part. I forgot, that I overrided setHighlighted function in my custom UITableViewCell subclass. I wanted to change color of tapped cell. How should I do it instead of what I did? Answer updated

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the reason why cells with `selectionStyle` set to `.none` got highlighted on tap. Because of me overriding `setHighlighted` method (as shown in the question) of `UITableViewCell` I added **`shouldHighlightRowAt`** method like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Thanks everybody for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the selection style per cell in code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = table.dequeue...

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
    } else {
        cell.selectionStyle = .default
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in cellForRowAt add cell.selectionStyle = .none

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     if(indexPath.section == desiredSection){
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell;
     }
```